# C# Windows forms график функции

Tags: c#, winforms, диаграммы

Всем привет есть такая проблема нужно сделать график линейной функции, какой `SeriesChartType` чтобы график выглядел[image: введите сюда описание изображения] так

`System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting`; стандартная для построение графиков
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.seriescharttype?view=netframework-4.8 здесь подробнее про SeriesChartType но нужного решения не нашёл

```
Chart myChart = new Chart();
myChart.Parent = this;
myChart.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
myChart.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea("y=kx"));
Series mySeriesOfPoint = new Series();
mySeriesOfPoint.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
mySeriesOfPoint.ChartArea = "y=kx";
```

Comment: Не проблем, нужно, так делайте. :) "какой `SeriesChartType`" - а какие есть варианты? О какой библиотеке речь?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.seriescharttype?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting; стандартная для построение графиков

Comment: Для простоты чтения вопроса перепишите эту информацию в сам пост. И сформулируйте вопрос, укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности, покажите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Comment: Вот, другое дело.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто задайте все необходимые свойства. В частности, `Crossing`, чтобы были оси координат. И сами значения функции в `AddXY`.

```
var area = new ChartArea("y=kx");
area.AxisX.Crossing = 0;
area.AxisY.Crossing = 0;

var series = new Series();
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
series.ChartArea = "y=kx";

var chart = new Chart();
chart.Parent = this;
chart.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

chart.ChartAreas.Add(area);
chart.Series.Add(series);

int k = 1;
for (int x = -10; x <= 20; x += 10)
{
    int y = k * x;
    series.Points.AddXY(x, y);
}
```

И советую не удлинять имена префиксами наподобие "my".

Comment: спасибо работает